# Impala minimum DDL

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, impala

I know that we can create an Impala table like

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE SCHEMA.TableName LIKE PARQUET
'/rootDir/SecondLevelDir/RawFileThatKnowsDataTypes.parquet'
```

But I am not sure if Impala can create a table from a file (preferably a text file) that has no known formatting.  So in other words if I just dump a random file into hadoop with a put command, can I wrap an Impala DDL around it and have a table created. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: But does the text file have any structure? Are you asking if Impala can determine the formatting automatically?

Comment: Sorry I didnt see this comment.  Yes thats what Im asking pretty much!

Comment: No, Impala has no such feature. It would be too complex and error-prone - think about a text file of chat messages with commas, semicolons, tabs and other punctuation characters; how would you determine the column delimiter programmatically? You need to define the formatting explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you file is newline separated I believe it should work if you provide the column delimiter with the ROW FORMAT clause, since textfile is the default format. Just get rid of your `LIKE` clause, and choose names and datatypes for your columns something like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE SCHEMA.TableName (col1 STRING, col2 INT, col3 FLOAT)
'/rootDir/SecondLevelDir/RawFile'
row format delimited fields terminated by ",";
```

Comment: But I want impala to have the proper number of columns and maybe imply some data types, similar to bcp in a traditional RDBMS

Comment: i don't get what you're asking, do you know the column delimiter?

Comment: does my answer help you now?

Comment: The assumption here is that you know nothing of the file.  I don't want to have to give the column data types.  I am wondering if Impala will infer the column data types.  Or is that not possible?